# android device monitor not working in android studio

Tags: android

I am using Android studio 1.2.2. 
My android device monitor is not running.
This is the error -
An error has occured. See the log file...
And the log file contains-

```
!SESSION 2015-06-15 14:31:36.524 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.099
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.107
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.112
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.170
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.174
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108-092756.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.177
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.182
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.192
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_4.2.2.v20130121-200410.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.198
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.100.v20120524-0627.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.202
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.201.v20130125-135424.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.207
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.213
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.964
    !MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.964
    !MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/ was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.964
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.964
    !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.964
    !MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.1.v20121109-203239.jar was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.964
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.964
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.964
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.964
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524/ was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.analysis 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.400.v20120912-130548.jar was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.jasper.servlet_[0.0.0,6.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.965
    !MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.7.0.v20120523-1543.jar was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.966
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.core_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.966
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.966
    !MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20120912-130548.jar was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.966
    !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.997
    !MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.997
    !MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.lucene_2.9.1.v201101211721 [25] was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.997
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.997
    !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.analysis_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.997
    !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.highlighter_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.997
    !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.memory_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.997
    !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.queries_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.snowball_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.spellchecker_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.misc_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.1.v201101211721 [26] was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.analysis 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.1.v20121109-203239 [91] was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.400.v20120912-130548 [94] was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.jasper.servlet_[0.0.0,6.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20120912-130548 [95] was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_0.0.0.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522 [138] was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522 [139] was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.eclipse.jetty.jmx_8.0.0.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.security_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.998
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.7.0.v20120523-1543 [147] was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.core_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200 [150] was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.search_3.8.0.v20120523-1540 [152] was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.search 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524 [164] was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_3.4.400.v20120705-114010 [166] was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources 2 0 2015-06-15 14:31:37.999
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-15 14:31:38.003
    !MESSAGE Application error
    !STACK 1
    java.io.IOException: The folder "C:\Users\Dishant%20Gupta\.android\monitor-workspace\.metadata" is read-only.
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.lock(BasicLocation.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.set(BasicLocation.java:164)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.set(BasicLocation.java:137)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorApplication.start(MonitorApplication.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

My sdk is up to date and my android studio also. My jdk and sdk path is also correct.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer, it was due to the 32 bit windows.
May be android studio is not fully compatible with 32 bit windows.
to open android device monitor you can go to AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86\monitor.exe to directly open it.
You have to run it as an administrator.
Then it will work normally.